# Jquery Make a Div a Clickable Form Area

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

The form:

```
  <form action="includes/photos.php" id="joinPhotoUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  </form>
```

The div: (assume CSS width: 300px; and height: 300px;)

```
<div id="clickable"><div>
```

Is it possible using JQuery to make an entire DIV area only a form element and request the user to select/browse for an file?

Otherwise is there a way to do this with CSS? 
Note: I've tried using CSS and it works in Chrome but only parts of the DIV for FF & IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and whatever i understood check my implementation

http://jsfiddle.net/vBVkL/29/

let me know if i have misunderstood.

**UPDATED:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vBVkL/30/

Thanks